# Connecting to Informix database from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, informix

What's the best way to connect to a Informix database from .Net?

I'm developing a client-server application based on a legacy Informix DB which used to be connected by JDBC.

I need it, from the most important to the least:

1. To be fast
2. DB server changes not needed
3. No ODBC and no dependencies, other than de .Net Framework 2.0

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please select the answer that helped you most - if any of them helped at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The connections strings to use with OleDb or ADO.NET can be found [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/?carrier=informix).

Take a look at this [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/index.html) on how to connect to an Informix database using ADO.NET.

Comment: Ah wonderful. A 13 year old answer with 2 dead links.

Answer (score 1):

We connect to Informix from .NET, but we do it via web services that are written in FourJ's BDL

Answer (score 0):

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.relnotes.doc/uc3/netrel.htm

See if that helps. Also, what about the built in ODBC or OLEDB drivers? Have you tried those? Those might work.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to investigate OpenLink's Multi-Tier Informix driver for ADO.Net (just install everything on the client): http://uda.openlinksw.com/dotnet/mt/dotnet-informix-mt/