# Connecting to Informix using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, database-connection, informix

**Server Information**
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.8       Generic Patch   October 2001
Server: Informix Dynamic Server Version 7.31.UD3

**Information:**

- Link: [Connecting to Informix database from .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192477/connecting-to-informix-database-from-net)
- Article: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/db2/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/
- I am running Visual Studio 2010 (C# 4.0).
- I don't care if it is ODBC vs OLE DB.
- I uninstalled all the client SDKs for Informix. I have readily available the IBM Informix CSDK 3.5 ready to be installed (the article uses 2.9 in its example, but I can't find that anywhere).
- I have the sample code from the article.

Basically, I was unsuccessful at connecting to the Informix DB. I have since removed all signs of the Client SDK. At this point, I have no idea what to do. I don't know if I'm using the right version ConnectionDriver or not, or if I can somehow use a dll and setup the connection internally in VS.NET, but nothing seems to work. Any help just getting a connection to work would be great:

**[Sample Code](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/apps/download/index.jsp?contentid=95047&filename=IfxAdo.zip&method=http&locale=) (From the article):**

```
using System;
using IBM.Data.Informix;

namespace IfxAdoPres.Basics {
    public class BasicConnection {
        const string HOST = "192.168.OBFUSCATED";
        const string SERVICENUM = "1525"; //Port?
        const string SERVER = "serverOBFUSCATED";
        const string DATABASE = "dbOBFUSCATEDy";
        const string USER = "myusername";
        const string PASSWORD = "mypassword";

        public IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection();

        public BasicConnection() {}

        public void MakeConnection()
        {
            string ConnectionString =
                "Host = "   + HOST       + "; " +
                "Service="  + SERVICENUM + "; " +
                "Server="   + SERVER     + "; " +
                "Database=" + DATABASE   + "; " +
                "User Id="  + USER       + "; " +
                "Password=" + PASSWORD   + "; ";
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("Made connection!");
            }
            catch (IfxException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think IfxConnection is the IBM Informix .NET provider, not the OleDB provider, so the connection string is slightly different http://www.connectionstrings.com/informix#p46 but I don't know if that matters. I'm fairly sure I've done this both with IfxConnection and OdbcDbConnection but I don't have code to hand sorry - maybe later.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure why, but apparantly uninstalling and reinstalling made it work... not sure what was wrong prior. I guess we can mark this as closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All it took was a fresh reinstall... removed all the old drivers and installed a fresh new 3.5 CSDK, then used the demo code from the article and used the Setnet32 to configure my connection.

Comment: The only thing I could add is, Windows 7 doesn't play nice with the 64 bit library by IBM. I have had to re-install multiple times already. I want to believe my install has something else besides the Informix going bad. In an unrelated topic I had to add manually the path to the folder where the .dll is contained to the System environment Path(as in program files/IBM SDK/Bin/netf20/dll)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void MakeConnection() {
    string ConnectionString = "Host=" + HOST + "; " +
     "Service=" + SERVICENUM + "; " +
     "Server=" + SERVER + "; " +
     "Database=" + DATABASE + "; " +
     "User Id=" + USER + "; " +
     "Password=" + PASSWORD + "; ";

    IfxConnection conn = new IfxConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    try {
        conn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Made connection!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    } catch (IfxException ex) {
        Console.WriteLine("Problem with connection attempt: "
                          + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

See: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/

Comment: That's identical to the code he already had (barring the exception text)