# IBM.Data.Informix.dll throws Exception c# connection informix

Tags: c#, connection, informix

I try to connect to informix server 11.5 using using IBM.Data.Informix (located in `C:\Program Files\IBM\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER\bin\netf20_32\IBM.Data.Informix.dll`). I'm using vb2008 and when I try to connect throws an error `invalid argument`.

Where is the problem? Thanks

```
    public static IfxConnection MAkeConnInformix()
    {
        IfxConnection cnn = new IfxConnection();
        string error = "";
        try
        {
            string ConnectionString = Database=mydbname;Host=10.8.8.50;Server=mainserver_net;Service=1526; Protocol=onsoctcp;UID=myuser;Password=mypass";
            cnn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
        }
        return cnn;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407093/connecting-to-informix-using-net

Comment: try removing 'Protocol=onsoctcp' do you have 32 or 64 bit drivers?

Comment: Do you have to use IBM.Data.Informix? If not, you could use [IBM Data Server .NET provider](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1007dsnetids/index.html?ca=drs-) since IBM Informix .NET Provider `is no longer being enhanced for new .NET APIs`.

Comment: ok, now, i try with 32bits drivers and throws a new exception "SQL_INFX_ATTR_LOCALIZE_DECIMALS"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot connect because something is wrong with locale then add properties to your connect string. I do not use .net, but in JDBC such Informix connect string with Polish locale info looks like:

```
jdbc:informix-sqli://127.0.0.1:9088/test_db:informixserver=ol_local;DB_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;CLIENT_LOCALE=pl_PL.CP1250;charSet=CP1250
```

In Listing 1 on http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/ there is example that says that DB_LOCALE and others can be add to .net connet string/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Informix have two native drivers: SQLI and DRDA (or Data Server Driver). You are referencing DRDA driver but you are using connection string syntax from SQLI driver. For example keyword protocol exist only in SQLI. Differences between drivers and sample connection strings are here: [Get started with the IBM Data Server .NET Provider for Informix](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1007dsnetids/index.html)

List of all keywords: [IBM Data Server Driver configuration keywords](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v115/topic/com.ibm.net_cc.doc/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/c0054698.htm) - difficult to use because most of it is irrelevant in case of Informix.