# Informix connection string field descriptions and values to be used

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, informix

I am writing a test application in `.net` using `c#` to connect to IBM's Informix database.

So far what i did is, i installed `Informix client sdk v4.10` in my machine. After that i wrote a piece of code referring from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407093/connecting-to-informix-using-net) and [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0510durity/index.html). In my code i have a reference to `IBM.Data.Informix.dll` which is referred from installed path of `Informix client sdk's` bin folder `netf40`.

When i run a test application, i am getting below error while trying to opening up an connection,

> ERROR [HY000] [Informix .NET provider][Informix]System error occurred
>   in network function.

i assume this error is due to connection string field not been supplied properly, i referred https://www.connectionstrings.com/informix/ and tried using connection string like `informix with ODBC driver and informix .net provider` mentioned in above link but no use, i am also having difficulty in understanding from where to get values for each connection string fields like `protocol, port, host-name , server-name and service name.`

To find values of above fields, i tried looking for SQLHOSTS key in registry entries under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\INFORMIX\` unfortunately it wasn't there! and also tried running `setnet32.exe` from client sdk's bin folder and i could see below screen with only `protocol` info!.

[image]

It would be really helpful if anyone can help me.

Comment: http://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-3.00.02-manual-html/t_fgl_odiagifx_005.html

Answer (score 1):

This is a very, very difficult question to answer blind. :-)

setnet32.exe will not know the information you are looking for, you need to provide this information to setnet32.exe.

The first question to ask is: is your database running on Unix or Linux? If it is, then by logging in to the database server as user "informix" and running the command

```
cat $INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts
```

If you're on Windows, then login to the Windows server and from a command prompt, run

```
TYPE %INFORMIXDIR%\etc\sqlhosts
```

This should give you a file with potentially a bunch of information, you're looking for lines that are not comments and have at least 4 columns. This is my sqlhosts file on a Docker I'm testing:

```
$ cat $INFORMIXDIR/etc/sqlhosts
############################################################
### DO NOT MODIFY THIS COMMENT SECTION
### HOST NAME = 7edf3045c382
############################################################
informix        onsoctcp        7edf3045c382         9088
informix_dr     drsoctcp        7edf3045c382         9089
```

The last two lines are the guts of the file.

- Column 1 is the name of the INFORMIXSERVER or an alias (IBM Informix Server in setnet32.exe)
- Column 2 is the protocol name (Protocolname in setnet32.exe)
- Column 3 is the host name (HostName in setnet32.exe)
- Column 4 is the port number or name (Service name  in setnet32.exe)

If column 4 is a name and you're on Unix or Linux, then search for the port name in /etc/services on your Unix or Linux server. If you're on Windows, then it will be in %windir%\system32\drivers\etc\services (or similar).

Once you have that, you can then run the command

```
dbaccess
```

Choose the Database option, followed by the Select option. This should present you with a list of databases, roughly like:

```
SELECT DATABASE >>
Select a database with the Arrow Keys, or enter a name, then press Return.

------------------------------------------------ Press CTRL-W for Help --------

 backbone@informix   wallet@informix

 cust@informix

 retail@informix

 sports@informix

 sysadmin@informix

 sysha@informix

 sysmaster@informix

 sysuser@informix

 sysutils@informix
```

In general, databases called "sys" are reserved for Informix administration, and may not be actual databases, although you can query them with SELECTs, you probably won't be able to (and really shouldn't!!) INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE or use DDL.

In my database list above, all the sys* databases are Informix administration "databases". Database names are shown in my example in "databasename@informixservername" format.

You should now have all the information you need to access your database.