# How I can access Database running in UNIX OS using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm new in ASP.NET Programming .. I want to build a simple program which communicates Informix-Database running on HP-UNIX server. I have the following information:

DB Name
Server IP
Username
Password

I want to know how I can establish a connection through my ASP program?

Thank you for your help

Safraawi

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/192477/connecting-to-informix-database-from-net

Answer (score 3):

Use an appropriate connection string in your configuration and whatever .NET database provider there is for your database of choice.

See [Connection Strings and Configuration Files (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx) on MSDN.

[connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/) is a good resource for connection strings - how they should be structured using the kind of data you have.

And [here](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=86) is a list of .NET data providers, though you should check for one from you database vendor. Infomix appears to have such a provider, based on the [release notes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.relnotes.doc/300xc2/netrel.html).

Comment: Dear Oded,
Thank you very much. is this correct?
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Database=myDataBase;Host=192.168.2.1;Server=register@online.net;Service=9005; Protocol=onsoctcp;UID=root;Password=toor");

Comment: @safraawi - I don't know. I have no idea about informix. The sample for .NET on connectionstrings.com would suggest that it should be: `Provider=Ifxoledbc;Data Source=myDataBase@192.168.2.1;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`